# Navigating through a file lines - C

Tags: c, file, io

Is there any way to navigate through a file with the option of moving up and down the line number instead of sequentially?

As of now, my code uses fgets to get the last line of ascii characters within the file, but through my research, I haven't found a smarter way of iterating through the file.

For example:

```
file.txt contains:

"hello\n"
"what's up?\n"
"bye"
```

I need to be able to return "bye" at first, but then using key presses, print "what's up\n", and go back down to "bye" through another key press.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do something like this by `mmap`-ing the whole file into memory, allowing you to treat the whole file as an array, and move around by searching for newline characters as bounds, copying out what falls between a pair of newlines.

Comment: Can you please show me an example? I'm not familiar with mmap.

Comment: [`mmap` docs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). Once you've actually performed the `mmap`, it's just like any other C array, so you can just loop, use `strchr`, etc. on it, as if it were a `char*` pointing to a giant array of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *infile;
    char *infile_contents;
    unsigned int infile_size;

    // to read all of the file
    infile = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    infile_size = ftell(infile);
    fseek(infile, 0,SEEK_SET);
    infile_contents = malloc(infile_size+1);
    fread(infile_contents, infile_size, 1, infile);
    fclose(infile);
    infile_contents[infile_size]=0;

    // to store the beginning of lines and replace '\n' with '\0'
    size_t num_lines = 1, current_line = 1, length;
    char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char*)), **lines1, *tmp;
    lines[0] = infile_contents;
    while(tmp = strchr(infile_contents, '\n'))
    {
        // to resize lines if it is not big enough
        if(num_lines == current_line)
        {
            lines1 = lines;
            lines = malloc((num_lines<<1)*sizeof(char*));
            memcpy(lines, lines1, num_lines*sizeof(char*));
            memset(lines+num_lines, 0, num_lines*sizeof(char*));
            num_lines <<= 1;
            free(lines1);
        }

        *tmp=0;
        infile_contents = tmp+1;
        lines[current_line++] = infile_contents;
    }

    // to print the lines
    num_lines = current_line-1;
    current_line = num_lines;

    // to skip the last line if it is empty
    if(!lines[current_line][0])
    {
        num_lines--;
        current_line = num_lines;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("%s",lines[current_line]);
        if(getchar())// change to the condition for going down
        {
            if(current_line)
                current_line--;
            else
                current_line=num_lines;
        }
        else
        {
            if(current_line==num_lines)
                current_line=0;
            else
                current_line++;
        }
    }
}
```